# Mysql Select with select result in an other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need some help, I don't know correct term of what im trying to do so im not able to find any example of what im trying to acheive.

Im hopping someone on here could just point me how how i could do this simple query and il be able to create one on my own.

```
SELECT * FROM
 `product_views` pv,`product_sales` ps
WHERE
 pv.`SessionId` = ps.`SessionId` {result of} ps.`ProductId` = 1
```

The syntax im trying to figure out is basacly how to get result of a query in a where clause.

Thanks!

Edit.
I realize that the fact that I don't know correct terms of what im trying to achieve is confusing so il show how in this point of time I would get the same result but in two query

```
SELECT ps.`SessionId` FROM `product_sales` ps WHERE ps.`ProductId` = 1;
```

Then with that the result of that query I would have let say sessionId `20` ( to keep it simple )
And then i would have to re-query with

```
SELECT * FROM `product_views` pv WHERE pv.SessionId = {ValueOfLastQuery};
```

Comment: are you looking for `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: when it comes to questions like this, it always makes it easier with data sample and expected results.

Comment: Use common English and explain what you're trying to do.  It appears you want all records from product_Views joined with product sales based on session Id..  Also look at [this blog article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for a better understanding of how joins work.  maybe you want a compound where clause and use of an `AND` Operator  `where  pv.SessionId = ps.SessionId AND ps.ProductId = 1`?

Comment: I just updated my post with the actual way i would resolve this problem with two query

Comment: You're simply after a compound where clause change {result of} to and and you'll have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join would help you achieve what you're looking for. [Here's](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php) a great introduction.

Basically, you'd want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
product_views
LEFT JOIN product_sales
ON product_views.SessionId = product_sales.SessionId
WHERE product_sales.ProductId = '1'
```

Edit:

I think you could also use a subquery, which would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
product_views
WHERE SessionId = (SELECT SessionId from product_sales WHERE ProductId = '1')
```

Comment: I may be wrong. But i think a INNER JOIN will return me both tables row. Im not sure though Is your example valid for me at this point ?

Comment: You're looking for rows from the `product_views` table that have the same `SessionId` as rows from the `product_sales` table, and where those rows in the `product_sales` table have a `ProductId` of `1`, right?

Comment: @Donald Changing that `INNER` to `LEFT` would have no effect on your end results.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The subquery is the more appropriate approach here.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.
I should have knew to search for "SubQuery" lol  But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about a subquery:

```
 SELECT * FROM `product_views` pv 
 WHERE pv.SessionId IN 
    (SELECT ps.`SessionId` FROM `product_sales` ps WHERE ps.`ProductId` = 1)
```

Comment: Id like to thank you for your input. You had what i need from the start
But you both gave me that awnser at the same time. So I gave the awnser to Donald,.  Thanks for your time. :)